# How do I use mod_deflate in Apache 2.4.1 with Haproxy?

Tags: apache, haproxy, mod-deflate

I have a strange issue whereby including the following syntax in my Apache 2.4.1 httpd.conf causes "502 Bad Gateway" errors when retrieving swf files via HAproxy:

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript text/javascript
```

When I remove this config line the 502 Bad Gateway error goes away.

The server returns these response headers on a successful request:

```
Date: Wed, 11 Apr 2012 20:24:12 GMT
Server: Apache
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

200 OK
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by updating to Apache 2.4.2 (there was a mod_deflate seg fault bug in 2.4.1) and adding:

`Header append Vary User-Agent`

Beneath the `AddOutputFilterByType` line.